# can I use select statement for ifnull function?

Tags: mysql

I need to select a value from a table according to its date. If the record does not exists in the target table, I want to replace it with another value as defualt value instead of Null. 
Can I do this with ifnull() function?

I have written this piece of code in a procedure, but I only get Null value for this field.

```
     CREATE PROCEDURE `test`(IN report_date DATE)
     BEGIN
        DECLARE initial_stock INT UNSIGNED;

        SET initial_stock = (select DISTINCT gs_fuel_type.fuel_initial_stock
                             from gs_fuel_type 
                             WHERE gs_fuel_type.fuel_type_id = 2 );

        drop TEMPORARY table if EXISTS temp_daily_fuel;
        create TEMPORARY TABLE temp_daily_fuel (
           fuel_stock INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0 
         );

        insert into  temp_daily_fuel (fuel_stock)
        select distinct 
        (select ifnull(gs_fuel_stock.fuel_remainder , initial_stock) 
            from gs_fuel_stock
            where   gs_fuel_stock.fuel_type_id = 2
                and gs_fuel_stock.shift_date = date_sub(report_date , INTERVAL 1 day)
        ) as fuel_stock 

        FROM shifts_view
        where   shifts_view.shift_date = report_date
        AND shifts_view.fuel_type_id = 2
        GROUP BY  shifts_view.fuel_type_id;    

     select  * from temp_daily_fuel ;

    END
```

Why { select ifnull(gs_fuel_stock.fuel_remainder , initial_stock) ....  } still returns null and doesn't replace the initial_stock value for this statement?

and I am quite sure that initial_stock value is not null.

The simplified Version of this code:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE `test`(IN report_date DATE)
        BEGIN
           DECLARE i INT UNSIGNED;

           SET i = (select DISTINCT g.i from g WHERE g.id = 2 );

           drop TEMPORARY table if EXISTS t;
            create TEMPORARY TABLE t (
                f INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0 
                );

           insert into  t (f)
                select distinct  
            (select ifnull(gs.r , i) from gs 
                where  gs.id = 2 and gs.date = date_sub(report_date , INTERVAL 1 day) ) as f 
             FROM a
               where a.date = report_date AND a.id = 2
                  GROUP BY  a.id;    

               select  * from t ;
            END
```

in this code, I want the value of "i" to be replaced instead of showing NULL.

Comment: Print the value of `initial_stock` after setting it.

Comment: @AbdulManaf what do you mean? The result of (select DISTINCT gs_fuel_type.fuel_initial_stock
                             from gs_fuel_type 
                             WHERE gs_fuel_type.fuel_type_id = 2 ) is 54500 in the gs_fuel_type table

Comment: Yes  , you can add a statement `SELECT initial_stock ;` after this query and once you call the SP it would print the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank everyone who tried to help me on this problem, I managed to solve it myself.
It turned out that the IFNULL() was functioning correctly, but the problem was that the query result was not null, it simply didn't exist!!!

So, I solved it with 'if not exists' and set the result to Null. after that, the IFNULL() function worked as I expected.

Here's my solution:
 first of all, I need a new variable "remains":

```
     DECLARE remains INT;
```

after that, I used the if structure:

```
    if not exists 
    (select gs_fuel_stock.fuel_remainder
    from gs_fuel_stock
    where   gs_fuel_stock.fuel_type_id = 2
            and gs_fuel_stock.shift_date = date_sub(report_date , INTERVAL 1 day))
then
    set remains = null;

end if;
```

finally, it's time to use ifnull:

```
     select ifnull(remains , initial_stock)
```

and it's done!

Answer (score 0):

Start with this simplification:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t
INSERT INTO t
    SELECT ... -- Keep this; toss the other parts
SELECT FROM t
```

Then look around for other simplifications.

Read up on `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` -- it *may* be the ultimate simplification.

After all that, I may be able to see what you are asking about (IFNULL).

Comment: Dear Rick, Thank you for your response. I edited my question and added the simplified version at the end.